Geometry Nodes: randomly change z scale of one object inside a collection instance, with other objects changing Z position accordingly
I have a bunch of buildings, each with the same GN modifier, where I scatter antennas on their tops.

The antennas are not one single object, but multiple objects inside a collection.

What I'm trying to do is to have the vertical poles of the antennas to have random Z scale, and the rest of the parts to follow accordingly:

I wrapped my head around it with no solution. What seemed promising was to parent an empty to a vertex of the pole, and then parent all the other parts to the empty. Then, giving random Z scale in GN to just the pole objects using index. But this scales only one object, and stretches it.

Is it possible to achieve what I want in GN with just one collection, or do I have to create multiple ones with different scales?
I will have to create multiple types of antennas, so I was trying to see if there are ways to procedurally randomize each type.
Thanks in advance!


If you're okay with your instances to be realized (mandatory step if you want your antennas to have variable height without being stretched), you could create a vertex group on your antenna to select the bottom part of it. Then in GN, realize your instances, Set Position their bottom part accordingly, using the vertex group as a selection. Would it solve your question ? Alternatively, you could only realize and set position the pole of the antennas, keeping the top part of the antenna as an instance.

The simplest way might be making a bigger pole and simply moving the instances down.

Make the original antena longer -- no geometry nodes here (keep the origin at the bottom)
In geometry nodes, add a "set position" after "distribute points", connect a random z (min some negative value, max 0) to the "offset" of the "set position".

Done. Some poles will go inside the building, but this shouldn't cause any problem.

Dang, simple but probably the best solution!
